# Dereference an object in Java

Tags: java, object, arraylist

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>();

tmp.add(1);
tmp.add(2);
tmp.add(3);
res.add(tmp);
```

And then I need to modify the tmp:

```
tmp.remove(tmp.size() - 1);
```

How can I modify the tmp with nothing changed in the res? Cause if I modify the tmp in this way, the content in res will be modified too. I thought this is relate to the dereference in Java, and maybe a very common and important question, so can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To leave the old `ArrayList` alone, [copy the existing `ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29) and assign it to `tmp`:

```
tmp = new ArrayList<Integer>(tmp);
```

Now you can work on a copy of the list without affecting the old list.

Comment: So, this kind of copy is deep copy or shallow copy?

Comment: This is a shallow copy.

Comment: Thanks, so the idea here, is instead of putting a reference into the Arraylist, just create a copy and put it there, right?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for

```
res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(tmp));
```

The idea is to create a copy of the object, rather than using the same reference in multiple places.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a copy of the `List` and store the *copy* in `res`:

`res.add(new ArrayList<Integer>(tmp));`

Just bear in mind that while the list is a copy, the objects in the lists are the same. So if you make a change to an object in one list, the object in the *copy* will be changed as well. Unless you do a deep copy of the original list.